# can we have a command line arguments in flutter build command just like the one for Flutter run (flutter run -t lib/main_di.dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

When generating an apk/ipa. Is it possible to pass command-line arguments along the **flutter build apk --release --target-platforms = [android-arm32/android-arm64] -t lib/main_di.dart**

is that possible?

the scenario is that, I have an app that should have a theme, background images and wording differently, however, the code base is the same and the structure of the screen/screens is the same.

so I need to know what I build to link to the appropriate assets and database.